# Gooogle play store

Tags: google-play-store

Keep getting a pop up informing me that that my Google play servecis has stopped. I have restarted my tablet but not getting any joy. Samsung tablet

Answer (score 1):

If restarting the device has not worked, you can try the following and see if it gets resolved

### Try clearing the app caches and app data of

- Google Play Services
- Google Services Framework
- Google Play Store

If it persists try uninstalling the updates of Google Play Store app from

### Settings->Apps/Apps Manager->Google Play Store->Uninstall Updates->Ok

now restart the device and launch Google Play Store app.